# phonegap build for kitkat

Tags: phonegap-build, tablet, android-4.4-kitkat, phonegap

I have made a phonegap app which works on all other devices except my tablet which runs KitKat(the app installs but displays a blank white screen instead of the content). I checked to see if this was an issue with it being a tablet but it seems to be the android version as the exact same app build works on another tablet running android lollipop...

This is the code in my config file, is there something else I need to add or something I should remove so that it will run correctly on the KitKat tablet?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.helloworld"
   version="1.0.0"
   xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
   xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
   xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest" mode="merge">
       <supports-screens
             android:xlargeScreens="true"
             android:largeScreens="true"
             android:smallScreens="true"
             android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
          />
       <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
  </config-file>


  <name>My App</name>
  <description>
   Tablet App.
   </description>

  <content src="index.html"/>
  <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19"/>
  <preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
  <access origin="*"/>
</widget>
```

I am not using an plugins, and am using build.phonegap to build my app.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get the google chrome remote device debugger working and it was an error in my code: I had used let instead of var and KitKat does not recognize let.

I changed all my let declarations to var and now it works perfectly.